# PHPMailer: Failed to connect to server: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm trying to send an email using PHPMailer and the code below, but i get this error:

> 2017-10-10 17:39:33 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server:
>   php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not
>   known (0) 2017-10-10 17:39:33 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server:
>   php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not
>   known (0) SMTP connect() failed.
>   https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Message
>   could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.
>   https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshootingfas

```
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

    require 'vendor/autoload.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'myaccount@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = '*********';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
    $mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
    $mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
    $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

    //Attachments



    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
     echo 'Message has been sent';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      echo 'Message could not be sent.';
      echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
```

Comment: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#dns-failures Update your question with your troubleshooting results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You realise this is an example using placeholder data? `example.*` domains are [guaranteed not to exist](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6761), specifically so they can be used safely in example code and documentation. You need to substitute your own domains for all those example addresses, and then DNS lookups will work (which is what is failing for you at the moment).